# Node Driver startup issue V1

Tags: driver, corda

I am running into an issue after upgrading a custom cordapp from M13 to V1. I have a small test suite which launches nodes using the node driver, and after upgrading to version 1 I get an issue which seems to be caused by the cordadevcakeys.jks file being null (see the error stack below). To upgrade I simply changed the build gradle release version and gradle plugins version from 0.13.0 to 1.0.0 - I am not sure if there is a step I am missing here that could potentially cause this error? I have also pulled the latests version 1 Corda project locally - although I was under the impression that this step isnt needed.

```
[ERROR] 12:45:26,017 [main] (Driver.kt:396) driver.DriverDSL.genericDriver - 
Driver shutting down because of exception
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at net.corda.testing.driver.DriverDSL.start(Driver.kt:796) ~[corda-node-driver-1.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.driver.Driver.genericDriver(Driver.kt:393) [corda-node-driver-1.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.driver.Driver.driver(Driver.kt:317) [corda-node-driver-1.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.driver.Driver.driver$default(Driver.kt:314) [corda-node-driver-1.0.0.jar:?]
at src.DeploymentTestKt.main(DeploymentTest.kt:29) [main/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:65) [idea_rt.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader.getSystemRes…ates/cordadevcakeys.jks") must not be null
at net.corda.testing.TestConstants$DEV_CA$2.invoke(TestConstants.kt:72) ~[corda-test-utils-1.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.TestConstants$DEV_CA$2.invoke(TestConstants.kt) ~[corda-test-utils-1.0.0.jar:?]
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at net.corda.testing.TestConstants.getDEV_CA(TestConstants.kt) ~[corda-test-utils-1.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.CoreTestUtils.getTestPartyAndCertificate$default(CoreTestUtils.kt:145) ~[corda-test-utils-1.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.CoreTestUtils.getBOC_IDENTITY(CoreTestUtils.kt:75) ~[corda-test-utils-1.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.CoreTestUtils.getBOC(CoreTestUtils.kt:76) ~[corda-test-utils-1.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.testing.CoreTestUtils.<clinit>(CoreTestUtils.kt:77) ~[corda-test-utils-1.0.0.jar:?]
... 10 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.corda.testing.CoreTestUtils
at net.corda.testing.driver.ShutdownManager.shutdown(Driver.kt:505)
at net.corda.testing.driver.DriverDSL.shutdown(Driver.kt:627)
at net.corda.testing.driver.Driver.genericDriver(Driver.kt:399)
at net.corda.testing.driver.Driver.driver(Driver.kt:317)
at net.corda.testing.driver.Driver.driver$default(Driver.kt:314)
at src.DeploymentTestKt.main(DeploymentTest.kt:29)
... 5 more
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.corda.testing.CoreTestUtils
at net.corda.testing.driver.ShutdownManager.shutdown(Driver.kt:505)
at net.corda.testing.driver.DriverDSL.shutdown(Driver.kt:627)
at net.corda.testing.driver.Driver$genericDriver$shutdownHook$1.invoke(Driver.kt:391)
at net.corda.testing.driver.Driver$genericDriver$shutdownHook$1.invoke(Driver.kt)
at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.ShutdownHookKt$addShutdownHook$hook$1.run(ShutdownHook.kt:15)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I can post the code I am using to launch the driver if need be, but by having a look at the cordapp-example it seems my method for starting the driver and nodes is correct, and it was working on M13.

*Edit, added in my gradle build and node driver code

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.publish-utils'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "../config/dev"
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "../config/test"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
    compileOnly "co.paralleluniverse:capsule:1.0.1"
    compile 'net.sourceforge.plantuml:plantuml:8039'

    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

    //Corda integration dependencies
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-jfx:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-webserver-impl:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-test-utils:$corda_release_version"
    testCompile "net.corda:corda-test-utils:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "net.corda:corda:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "net.corda:corda-webserver:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"
    //testCompile "net.corda:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"
    cordapp "net.corda:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"

//    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
//    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
//    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
//    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
//    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"
//    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-webserver-impl:$corda_release_version"
//    cordaRuntime "net.corda:corda:$corda_release_version"
//    cordaRuntime "net.corda:corda-webserver:$corda_release_version"
//    testCompile "net.corda:corda-test-utils:$corda_release_version"
//    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"
//    testCompile "net.corda:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"



}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        languageVersion = "1.1"
        apiVersion = "1.1"
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        javaParameters = true   // Useful for reflection.
    }
}

task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    networkMap "CN=Controller,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK"
    node {
        name "CN=Controller,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK"
        advertisedServices = ["corda.notary.validating"]
        p2pPort 10002
        rpcPort 10003
        cordapps = ["secLendModel"]
    }
    node {
        name "CN=NodeA,O=NodeA,L=London,C=UK"
        advertisedServices = []
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcPort 10006
        webPort 10007
        cordapps = ["secLendModel"]
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": []]]
    }
    node {
        name "CN=NodeB,O=NodeB,L=New York,C=US"
        advertisedServices = []
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcPort 10009
        webPort 10010
        cordapps = ["secLendModel"]
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": []]]
    }
    node {
        name "CN=NodeC,O=NodeC,L=Paris,C=FR"
        advertisedServices = []
        p2pPort 10011
        rpcPort 10012
        webPort 10013
        cordapps = ["secLendModel"]
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": []]]
    }
}

// TODO: Make into gradle plugin without any references to Jython
task installJythonDeps(dependsOn: ['build']) {
    project.copy {
        from project.configurations.runtime
        into "build/jythonDeps"
    }
}

installJythonDeps.shouldRunAfter build

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true // defaults to false
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        jarAndSources(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifactId 'secLendModel'

            artifact sourceJar
            artifact javadocJar
        }
    }
}

task runTemplateClientRPC(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.template.client.TemplateClientRPCKt'
    args 'localhost:10006'
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

and this is my node driver code

```
fun runSimulation() {
        driver(portAllocation = PortAllocation.Incremental(20000), isDebug = false, startNodesInProcess = true, extraCordappPackagesToScan = listOf("com.secLendModel")) {
            //Normal Users
            val arnoldParams = NodeParameters(providedName = ARNOLD, rpcUsers = arrayListOf(stdUser))
            val barryParams = NodeParameters(providedName = BARRY, rpcUsers = arrayListOf(stdUser))
            val colinParams = NodeParameters(providedName = COLIN, rpcUsers = arrayListOf(stdUser))
            val arnold = startNode(defaultParameters = arnoldParams)
            val barry = startNode(defaultParameters = barryParams)
            val colin = startNode(defaultParameters = colinParams)

            //Special Users (i.e asset issuers and oracles)
            val notaryParams = NodeParameters(providedName = NOTARY, advertisedServices = setOf(ServiceInfo(ValidatingNotaryService.type)))
            val notary = startNode(defaultParameters = notaryParams)
            //Stock issuer AND stock price oracle
            val exchangeParams = NodeParameters(providedName = EXCHANGE, rpcUsers = arrayListOf(specialUser),
                    advertisedServices = MARKET.plus(ServiceInfo(PriceType.type)))
            val exchange = startNode(defaultParameters = exchangeParams)
            //Cash issuer
            val centralbankParams = NodeParameters(providedName = CENTRALBANK, rpcUsers = arrayListOf(specialUser),
                    advertisedServices = CURRENCIES)
            val centralBank = startNode(defaultParameters = centralbankParams)
//            val oracle = startNode(ORACLE, advertisedServices = setOf(ServiceInfo(PriceType.type)))

            notaryNode = notary.get()
            arnoldNode = arnold.get()
            barryNode = barry.get()
            colinNode = colin.get()
            exchangeNode = exchange.get()
            centralNode = centralBank.get()
//            oracleNode = oracle.get()
            startWebserver(arnoldNode)

            setUpNodes()
            simulateTransactions()
            waitForAllNodesToFinish()
        }
```

Comment: Could you post your gradle build file? I think you might have missed upgrading a dependency.

Comment: Could you also post the node driver code?

Comment: @Jacob ive posted my gradle build file - I am not test compiling the node driver as I am actually calling it from within my main file within source not from testing.

Comment: @joel also posted the node driver code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close IntelliJ and clear out your gradle cache (under `~/.gradle` on Mac).

Comment: So this partially solved the issue. For anyone else who runs into this problem, I had to completely uninstall intellij (upgraded from 2017.1 to 2017.2), remove all gradle caches and also remove the local copy of my cordapp and repull from the repository. After doing this and reimporting the gradle project, everything works fine.